# React js rendering a large list of nested elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a very large list of 'nested' data  and I had to use 4 maps to extract all data and display it

the problem is when I click to redirect to this page it stuck for like half a second or sometimes more before even rendering the page

is there any solution on how  to place a loader until this map finish extracting data
something like  :

```
return ( 

      {  'map is still in progress'? <LoaderComponent/> : <ShowResult/>}
)
```

I tried something like the previous code  and  it shows the loader but  it didn't even start to map

Comment: Put it into `useEffect` and use state to keep track of when it's done...

Comment: There is something highly ineffective about your data structure if you have to use four nested loops to render it. That should probably be your foremost concern. There is almost nothing you can do to deal with the time the loops are taking, they are going to block painting no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

For large/expensive lists the best practice would be to use the hook `useMemo`

you can read more about it https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo

implemented as

```
const memoizedValue = useMemo(() => computeExpensiveValue(a, b), [a, b]);
```

the second argument being an array of dependencies, e.g. page number, keyPress values, etc.

but in your case you could just use

```
const memoizedValue = useMemo(() => _hugeArray, []);
```

and then map the memoizedValue in your template

```
{memoizedValue.map(el, i)=> <div key={i}>{el}</div>}
```

Note that any function passed to `useMemo` runs during rendering. Restrict side effects to your `useEffect` hook

Comment: it still the    same issue because useMemo will avoid the fetch each time I access the page

Comment: @benftimawajdi have you tried storing the value in redux store at the top level?

Comment: yeah I'm getting data from the redux store 
I think what I need is to access the page and then  rendering the view mean : 
something like holding the mapping process  and launch it when the  component is mounted
I don't know if this possible

Answer (score 0):

There's not much you can really do. In a scenario where you need to render a large list of items I'd recommend you check out [react window](https://react-window.now.sh/#/examples/list/fixed-size). It was written by a developer who contributed to React and it helps when rendering large lists by only rendering the items that are in the viewport.

I would add a quick implementation to my answer but I don't know what the components of your app look like.

Comment: I tied something like this ( lazy loading scroll), and it didn't help